# Can I put one module on another in DNN?

Tags: content-management-system, dotnetnuke

I developed 2 different modules, carousel and log in. I would like to know is it possible to place the log in module on the carousel module?
I would like my client to be able to change easily the Carousel Module with another one without affecting the Login Module (which is over the Carousel Module).

Thank you in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

If your carousel is capable of rotating modules, yet.

I believ ZLDNN and DNN Stuff both have modules that can rotate modules.